# SqlAlchemy FunctionElemen. How put method in class?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have class `UtcNow` and method `pg_utc_now`. How put method `pg_utc_now` in class `UtcNow`?

```
    class UtcNow(expression.FunctionElement):
        type = DateTime()
    
    
    @compiles(UtcNow, 'postgresql')
    def pg_utc_now(element, compiler, **kw):
        return "TIMEZONE('utc', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
```

I сan realize method `set_deleted` by using class `UtcNow`?

```
    class DeleteMixin(object):
        delete_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
    
        def set_deleted(self):
            # self.delete_at = UtcNow()
            pass
```